# jquery bind stoppropagation callback context

Tags: jquery, callback, bind, stoppropagation

I am trying to prevent multiple events firing.

I'm using a callback function to pass an object, like this:

```
function init() {

    var myObj = this.someObject;

    $('#id').bind("blur keyup change", function (e, obj) {
        return function () {
            SomeFunction(e, obj);
        }
    } (this, myObj));

}

function SomeFunction(e, obj) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //do something with the object
}
```

The error is that it can't find the function stopPropagation.

This is because I am assigning 'this' to e in the calling function.

How can I get access to the 'event' in SomeFunction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/W47Ky/

Comment: thank you. this has really helped me understand how to pass objects correctly. I am now having trouble with the context, i can no longer access root variables through 'e'. See http://jsfiddle.net/W47Ky/1/

Before i could access e.nameid, but now it is undefined.

Comment: I figured it out, i needed to pass ctx to the function as well. http://jsfiddle.net/W47Ky/2/